# Adding images in a leaflet map using json

Tags: jquery, leaflet, geojson

I have a json file, each line containing the filename and the bounding box:

```
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "name": "images\/gis\/json_Andros1.png" }, "geometry": { "type" : "LineString", "coordinates": [[37.8416750531,24.7951207305],[37.8418346487,24.7954102608]] }  }
```

And I access the file via:

```
var raster_group = new L.featureGroup([]);
$.getJSON($('link[id="rasters_geojson"]').attr("href"), function(data) { 
    var geojson = L.geoJson(data, {  
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            var rasterfilename = (String(feature.properties['name']));
            var rastercoordinates = L.GeoJSON.coordsToLatLngs(feature.geometry['coordinates'],0);
            alert(rasterfilename); alert(rastercoordinates);
            layer = new L.imageOverlay(rasterfilename, rastercoordinates); 
            return layer;
        }
    });
    geojson.addTo(raster_group);
});
```

The error is NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE:

And another question. How can I load only the images within the bounding box of the map?

Comment: Eventually ther will be hundrends of raster images on this map, so I must find a way to load only the ones needed for the view.

Answer (score 0):

Your line 
`var rastercoordinates = coordsToLatLngs(feature.properties['geometry'],0);`
 is missing the class of the method.
It should look like
`var rastercoordinates = L.GeoJSON.coordsToLatLngs(feature.properties['geometry'],0);`

Comment: Thank you, but the rasters are still not loaded. It looks as if the onEachFeature is not run at all.

Comment: Can you put this on a demo site so we can see it in action?

Comment: In http://aristeia.ha.uth.gr/site.php?id=10000040 you can see the project, but the images are loaded implicitely. What I want is to load only the raster images from the JSON that are within the map when the page is loaded.

Comment: To load images only inside the current map viewport..you will want to use `contains`.. It works with `LatLngBounds`. `var bounds = map.getBounds(); if (bounds.contains(rastercoordinates)) { show image}`  - docs at http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlngbounds-contains

Answer (score 0):

I would like to thank very much snkashis for his help. Things proved more complicated, though.

First, I had the problem of leaflet reversing the coordinates read from json. Then I had the problem of different types of objects, that turned errors in leaflet itself (too many recursions, undefined variables, etc.).

But the following code worked, so I upload it for other to use:

```
mapinitialbounds = map.getBounds();
var raster_group = new L.featureGroup([]);
    $.getJSON($('link[id="rasters_geojson"]').attr("href"), function(data) { 
        var geojson = L.geoJson(data, {  
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                var rasterfilename = (String(feature.properties['name']));
                var rastercoordinates = [feature.geometry['coordinates'][0],feature.geometry['coordinates'][1]];
                var line = new L.polyline(rastercoordinates);
                if (mapinitialbounds.contains(line.getBounds())) { 
                    layer = new L.imageOverlay(rasterfilename, rastercoordinates); 
                    layer.addTo(raster_group);
                }
                return layer;
            }
        });
    });
    map.addLayer(raster_group);
```

I find the need to create a polyline to get the bounds unneccesary complicated. Do you think the above code can be simplified?